# Manipulando parâmetros de objetos com múltiplos níveis em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um serviço dentro de uma aplicação angular onde eu utilizo uma Value para gerar uma espécie de sessão. pensando no cenário:

```
angular.module("app.values", [])
    .value("a", {
        b : {
            c : {
                d: "joao"
            }
        }
    })
;
```

Pensando no funcionamento de uma sessão simples basicamente eu teria 2 funções: **get**, **set**. Até o momento eu consegui pensar na função do tipo **get** que fica assim:

```
function get(object, param) {
    var level = param.split("."), value = object;
    for (var i in level) 
      value = value[level[i]];
    return value;
}
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo pensar em um método de fazer a função **set** para manipular somente o valor específico de um objeto, já pensei nisso até o momento...

```
function(object, param, value){
    var level = param.split("."), object = object, value = value;
    for(var i = 0; i < level.length; i++){
        //e agora?????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function set(object, param, value) {
  var levels = param.split('.');
  var lastLevel = levels.pop();
  get(object, levels.join('.'))[lastLevel] = value;
}
```